# Unexpand the script before executing for handling here document

Tags: bash, here-document

Let's consider the following code

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(
        cat <<-EOF
                Foo Bar
        EOF
)

echo "${var}"
```

This works as expected with tabs, i.e the `var` variable holds assigned `Foo Bar`

However, consider a situation where I cat out this file on terminal, and copy paste the content of this script to another file instead of using `cp` or `scp`

Now, the script would contain spaces instead of tabs, so the same script above would give errors with spaces instead of tabs

So, I would like to modify the script with `unexpand` before coninuing to execute the program always

I tried modifying the code above like so

```
#!/bin/bash

unexpand --first-only $0 | sponge $0

var=$(
        cat <<-EOF
                Foo Bar
        EOF
)

echo "${var}"
```

This works the second time around, and I know why that's happening

But I want to make this program run correctly the first time around, how do I modify my script so that it runs correctly the first time around with spaces instead of tabs

Note: I know this could be done by splitting the file into 2 separate scripts, but I do not want do that. I would like to have only one single script.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to modify the source of the script that's running seems like a path to nasal demons.

How about something like (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

: ${TMPDIR='/usr/tmp'}
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
tooldir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
if [[ "$tooldir" != "$TMPDIR" ]]; then
    # copying first to get the same permissions on the tmp as on the original
    cp "$0" "$tmpfile" &&
    unexpand --first-only "$0" > "$tmpfile" &&
    "$tmpfile" "$@"
fi

var=$(
        cat <<-EOF
                Foo Bar
        EOF
)

echo "${var}"
```